# What is the reason for the new_to_publish hook not working?

Tags: publish

this hook should normally be triggered on new post but it doesn't work

```
add_action("new_to_publish", "doSomething", 10,1);

function doSomething($post){

global $post;

$_SESSION['yeni'] = 'test';
}

echo $_SESSION['yeni'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new post, the initial post status is not `new`, but rather `auto-draft`. Try this:

```php
add_action("draft_to_publish", "doSomething", 10,1);

function doSomething($post){

    global $post;

    $_SESSION['yeni'] = 'test';
}

echo $_SESSION['yeni'];
```

Also note that you may want to make sure your session is properly initialized. To verify the callback works at least, enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and do something like

```php
add_action("draft_to_publish", "doSomething", 10,1);

function doSomething($post){
    error_log( 'Inside the new post transition');
}
```

Then publish a post and look at `wp-content/debug.log`

Comment: thanks so how can we do when post modified

Comment: There are several actions that fire when a post is updated, `edit_post_{$post->post_type}`, `edit_post`, and `post_updated`. You probably want the latter.

Comment: These codes bring the topic to the top when comments are made, as I comment on the topics, I want to capture them with the function and count them as if there are 5 current topics to the user.     array( 
            'post_modified' => current_time('mysql'),   // string
        ),

Comment: @MehmetCemil I'm not sure of exactly what you need here - it also seems like you might want to ask a new question for this as I can't tell if it's related.